# Why is my PHP upload script not working?

Tags: php, html, upload

I am doing some simple work with uploading a file.  I am ignoring error checking and exceptions at this point just to get my uploads working.  I have this HTML form:

```
<form action='addResult.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='results_iFrame' onsubmit='startUpload();'>
Entry: <input type='text' id='entry' />
Stop: <input type='text' id='stop' />
Final: <input type='text' id='final' />
Chart: <input type='file' id='chart' />
<input type='submit' value='Add' /></form>
```

As you can see, it calls 'addResult.php' within the iFrame 'results_iFrame'. The Javascript is just for animation purposes and to tell me when things are finished.
addResult.php has this code in it (along with processing the other inputs):

```
$upload_dir = "../img/";
$chart_loc = $upload_dir.basename($_FILES['chart']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['chart']['tmp_name'], $chart_loc);

print_r($_FILES);
```

It uses the 'chart' input from the form and tries to upload it. I have the print_r() function to display some information on $_FILES, but the array is empty, thus making this fail.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with forms, the `name=` is used to reference items serverside, not the `id=`.

Just change all those `id` attributes to `names`s, and you're good to go (hopefully).

Comment: "Just change all those name attributes to ids" - other way around, surely? :)

Comment: Whoops, contradicting myself again ;)

Comment: Ah, of course - it's always something simple.  I had converted this from sending information to a Javascript function that used the IDs and not Names.  Thanks!

Comment: I've pulled clumps of hair so many times because of the `name` and `id` thing, so no worries.

Comment: Same here. I still missed it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give your input elements `name` attributes or they don't get passed to your script. The `id` is used for DOM/browser/client-side use.

There might be another problem after you resolve this, but this is a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the name attribute to your input values like so:

```
<input type='file' id='chart' name="myfile"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs have no "name" attribute, only IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your form fields name attributes